# How to connect 2 views in the same Django app? (ListView and EditView)

Tags: python, django

I have 2 apps called Prospecto(which means Prospect) and Cliente(which means Customer).

When you see a register in EditView and click on its checkbox, you can indicate whether the register is still in Prospecto or Cliente

- If you don't click on the checkbox, that record is still in the Propsecto
- If you click the checkbox, that record becomes a Cliente and is no longer a Prospect

In the code I did, when I clicked the checkbox, it turns into record in Customer(that's ok), but I can't delete it from Prospecto(in ProspectoListView).

**views.py

```
class ProspectoListView(ListView):
    model = Prospecto
    template_name = 'prospectos.html'
    context_object_name = 'prospectos'
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        fecha_inicio = self.request.GET.get('fecha_inicio')
        fecha_fin = self.request.GET.get('fecha_fin')
        if fecha_inicio and fecha_fin:
            queryset = queryset.filter(fecha__range=[fecha_inicio, fecha_fin])
        elif fecha_inicio:
            queryset = queryset.filter(fecha__gte=fecha_inicio)
        elif fecha_fin:
            queryset = queryset.filter(fecha__lte=fecha_fin)
        return queryset



def ProspectoEditar(request, pk):
    prospecto = get_object_or_404(Prospecto, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProspectoForm(request.POST, instance=prospecto)
        if 'es_cliente' in request.POST:
            cliente = Cliente(nombre=prospecto.nombre)
            cliente.save()
            prospecto.es_cliente = True
            prospecto.delete()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('prospectos:prospectos_list')
    else:
        form = ProspectoForm(instance=prospecto)
    return render(request, 'prospectos-editar.html', {'form': form})
```

I try with this solution, adding delete() but it doesn't work

```
class ProspectoListView(ListView):
    model = Prospecto
    template_name = 'prospectos.html'
    context_object_name = 'prospectos'

    def get_queryset(self):
        fecha_inicio = self.request.GET.get('fecha_inicio')
        fecha_fin = self.request.GET.get('fecha_fin')
        queryset = super().get_queryset()

        if fecha_inicio and fecha_fin:
            queryset = queryset.filter(fecha__range=[fecha_inicio, fecha_fin])
        elif fecha_inicio:
            queryset = queryset.filter(fecha__gte=fecha_inicio)
        elif fecha_fin:
            queryset = queryset.filter(fecha__lte=fecha_fin)

        # Verificar si se ha enviado una solicitud POST para eliminar un prospecto
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            prospecto_id = self.request.POST.get('prospecto_id')
            if prospecto_id:
                prospecto = Prospecto.objects.get(pk=prospecto_id)
                prospecto.delete()

        return queryset
```

I mean, when I clicked the checkbox, that record is saved in Cliente and still in Prospecto too, and what I want for that register is become a client and disappear it from Prospecto.

Does anyone know how I can delete that record from my ListView? Thanks

Comment: are you sure the value check is actually true, prospecto_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
    if 'es_cliente' in request.POST:
        cliente = Cliente(nombre=prospecto.nombre)
        cliente.save()
        prospecto.es_cliente = True
        prospecto.delete()
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

You are deleting it if it is now a client, but then immediately resaving it.  Try the below

```
    if form.is_valid():
      if 'es_cliente' not in request.POST:
           form.save()
      else:
          cliente = Cliente(nombre=prospecto.nombre)
          cliente.save()
          #No point in updating a deleted record
          #prospecto.es_cliente = True
          prospecto.delete()
```